# Merge 2 columns into one via adding a new row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Which formula can I use to achieve this in Google Sheets?

[image: Example]

From:

```
Column  1 | Column 2
   1      |    2
   3      |    4
```

to:

```
1

2

3

4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A:B<>"", A:B&"♦", ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A:B<>"", A:B&"♦ ♦", )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "limit "&COUNTA(A:B)*2-1))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the formula you want to use is:

```
=transpose(split(A1, " | "))
```

Where `A1` contains the text `1 | 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this formula

```
=SORT({A:A;B:B})
```